# Is there a way to manipulate the Nvidia drivers on a MacBook Pro?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, macbook, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a MacBookPro3,1 (*not unibody*, the model right before) with an Nvidia GeForce 8600M GT 256MB.

On Windows/Linux machines one can usually manipulate the Nvidia driver to optimize performance, etc. I cannot find any similar feature in OS X. Is such a thing possible?

Are there any hacks or 3rd party drivers that would allow me to manipulate the Nvidia card?

Thanks -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NVIDIA supplies such tools, as you point out, as part of the drivers on Linux and Windows. There's nothing official supplied by NVIDIA for OSX. In addition, there are reports of your laptop's model overheating so it's probably not a good idea anyway.

The closest there seems to be is the [Graphiccelerator](http://thomas.perrier.name/graphiccelerator.html) tool but your card isn't under the list of supported ones.

I'd suggest this isn't possible on OSX as a result it's probably not exposed by the drivers so would be dangerous to try. I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: Seeing as I am on my 3rd logic board on this laptop, you are probably correct that it has some sort of heat issue.